# Modal window created with bPopup and url defined in a variable

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, bpopup

I am trying to create a model window using the bPopup plug in. What I think I don't understand is how to make the loadUrl a variable. I am not able to change the markup. Is the problem because it is a relative url and not fully qualified? I did try  `loadUrl:'http://site.name.org' + $(this).attr('href')` I am at a loss and any suggestions are appreciated.

```
$("<div id='element_to_pop_up'/>").appendTo("body");

$('.cit-thumbnail-link').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
        content:'iframe',
        contentContainer:'.content',
        loadUrl:$(this).attr('href')  
    });               
});
```

Markup

```
<a 
  href="/content/early/2012/11/12/jscr.rjs013.featured-figure.html"
  class="cit-thumbnail-link"
>
    <img 
      alt="Thumbnail"
      src="/content/early/2012/11/12/jscr.rjs013/embed/icon-1.gif"
      class="cit-thumbnail"
    >
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is the relative href you should send the raw content of it using :

```
this.href
```

instead of `$(this).attr('href')`.

That way you'll send loadUrl the full link.